# How to re-install a ubuntu package when sudo dpkg -i does not work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to re-install a broken package (tzdata) using dpkg but

```
 sudo dpkg -i tzdata_2014e-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb
```

does not work. Here's the output

```
dpkg: error processing tzdata_2014e-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb (--install):
unable to stat `./usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Europe/Bratislava' (which I was about to install): Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
tzdata_2014e-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb
```

?
I've tried --force-overwrite too. Any idea how I could re-install that package?

UPDATED

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Europe
```

gives

```
ls: cannot access /usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Europe/Bratislava: Input/output error
```

UPDATED2

I made a backup of the problematic directory elsewhere and tried to suppress it

```
 sudo cp -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/right ErrorDir
 cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Europe/Bratislava': Input/output error
 /usr/share/zoneinfo$ sudo rm -rf right
 rm: cannot remove `right/Europe/Bratislava': Input/output error
```

Same error code with apt-get -f install: Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid `Input/output error` indicates something more serious than just a broken package.

Comment: Just run a test, no problem with the disk.

Comment: Disk corruption is one possibility, another is deb file corruption. Can do further verification using `dpkg-deb -x`. Of course remember to decompress it in some temp folder.

Comment: What test did you perform? Was it a bad block test or S.M.A.R.T.? I bet a disk block is corrupted. Please run any low level test: `badblocks`, `smartct -a /dev/sda`, `smartct -t /dev/sda`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion [I eventually re-installed but will keep that in mind]. I think I checked for bad blocks at the time.